# Multivariant Testing for Components

Tags: content-testing

Can we apply for Multivariant testing on Static Components?
If Yes, then how or Is Multivariant testing recommended only for Dynamic Components?

Comment: By static do you mean no datasource?

Comment: Static Component means headers, footers etc..But that content hardly changes

Answer (score 1):

As long as a component has been added to a placeholder, it can be tested.  I assume by static component, you mean something like a breadcrumb that wouldn't typically be editable by a content author.  In that case, you could edit do an MV test from inside the presentation details.  I'd see this as an edge case and something that we'd want to keep content authors out of.  Hope I understood your question correctly.

[image: Non-editable component w/ test option present]

Comment: Thanks! JAmesDoes that mean from ContentAuthor perspective we can only do Dynamic MV test but outside Experience/Page Editor, MV test is possible for both Dynamic and Static Components.

Comment: That's my understanding.  You can do a test on any component.  I'd define static component as one that is flagged as un-editable by the author (as in the main navigation example above, from the habitat example).  I think it's more of a best practice distinction.  If you want the component to be testable it should be dynamic and available to the content editor w/in experience editor.